# I have a difficulties converting unicode to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 if accion == "Informe merma":

 bor=sum(map(int,QuesosFrescos1kgdanados))
 bora=str(bor)
 if bor >= 1:
    informe2.write("La cantidad de Queso Fresco de 1kg dañado ha sido de: "+bora+" unidades")
    informe2.write("\n")
    informe2.write("El porcentaje de merma en relacion al stock actual("+(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'"))+("), es de: ")+str(porcentajequesofresco1kg)+("%"))
    informe2.write("\n")
    informe2.write("\n")
```

Hi, I am trying to convert my "bor" variable to str because I have to write it on a document but I get a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbookpro-jonathanprieto/PycharmProjects/utec/programadiegotest.py", line 2130, in <module>
    informe2.write("La cantidad de Queso Fresco de 1kg dañado ha sido de: "+bora+" unidades")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have done it many times this way but now it doesn't work.

Pd: I am using python 3.

Comment: Could you post the full trace, not just line with the exception?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbookpro-jonathanprieto/PycharmProjects/utec/programadiegotest.py", line 2130, in <module>
    informe2.write("La cantidad de Queso Fresco de 1kg dañado ha sido de: "+bora+" unidades")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That error most probably comes from one of the `informe2.write()` lines, which in turn begs the question: How are you opening that file, and which encoding have you specified when opening it?

Comment: @JonathanPrieto I meant add it to the post by editing it, with code formatting, not post it in a comment. :)

Comment: \xf1 maps to ñ for anyone wondering.

Comment: You are right because i test it without the bora and I still have the same problem !

Answer (score 4):

It's not the variable `bora` that's triggering the error, but the `ñ` character.

Make sure you specify an encoding that can handle non-ASCII characters when opening the file, for example:

```
with open("informe2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as informe2:
    # do stuff
```

Besides, you don't have to convert `bor` to a string:

```
informe2.write("La cantidad de Queso Fresco de 1kg dañado ha sido de: {} unidades".format(bor))
```